# Get line number of start/end of current paragraph

Tags: vim, neovim

for the need of a script I'm currently writing, I'm trying to get in the fastest way possible the line number of the start/end of the current paragraph.

At first I was using `line("'{")` and `line("'}")`, but this actually is not working in this use case:

`1. this is a
2. paragraph
3.
4.
5. this is another paragraph
6. that is below the first one`

Indeed, when cursor is on line 4, `line("'{")` returns `1`, and `line("'}")` returns `6`, when I'd want it to be something like either `1/2` or `5/6`

I am reluctant to make the cursor move in order to get the wanted results, as those operations will be executed every time the user changes paragraph and moving cursor around is a bit slow.

If anyone knows a way to consistently get the lines numbers of the current paragraph start and end, I'd be glad to hear it!

Hope my question was clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of paragraphs is mostly based on empty lines, though [`:help paragraph`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#paragraph) also mentions some (rather obscure and inherited from vi) *nroff* macros that can define paragraphs.

- If you don't care about the obscure parts, and just base your definition on empty lines, you can use a `:while` loop together with `empty(getline(lnum))` to check for empty lines and thereby detect paragraphs yourself. This explicit iteration completely avoids cursor moves, but could be slow if there are very large paragraphs (spanning hundreds of lines).
- Your current approach only breaks down if the cursor currently is between paragraphs. You could explicitly check for that (again ignoring the obscure parts), and only then perform a jump, e.g. via `normal! {`.
- The easiest (and only one that's fully correct also for the obscure parts) implementation always jumps around. Inside a `:function`, screen updates only happen on demand (via `:redraw`). You need to save and restore the current view, so that the user doesn't notice:

```
let l:save_view = winsaveview()
" Code that jumps around here.
call winrestview(l:save_view)
```

If you prefix your motions with `:noautocmd` (or temporarily set [`:help 'eventignore'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27eventignore%27)), you can avoid that plugin actions (which can be far more costly than Vim's internal cursor moves) are triggered (on the `CursorMoved` event).

#### Summary

There are several options; which one is right for you, depends on your typical data and use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the input!
I didn't realise that what was causing slowness when moving cursor around was the autocmd that might have been triggering on the cursor move (and my plugin does indeed set an autocmd for the `CursorMoved` event.

Paragraphs should not be too large, I'll give a try to both solutions, but I feel like the one that moves the cursor around while disabling `autocmd` will do the trick!

Thanks a lot :)